# React - Unable to modify input of childs child entity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, setstate

I have this form to edit entries

Editing an entry allows you to edit it a child entity question

Editing a question entry brings up a modal to allow you to edit a child entity answer

When having the  `value={answer.content}` its unable to be edited. When removing this it can be edited but obviously if passing data the field will be empty.

Any suggestions on how to fix this and still be contained/mapped by the parent question?

code:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Modal, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function EditQuiz(props) {

  const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({title:"", timeLimit:"", value:"", hidden: ""})
  const [answerList, setAnswerList]=useState([{content:"a"},{content:"b"},{content:"c"},{content:"d"}]);

    const [questionList, setQuestionList]=useState( [ 
      { id: 1, question : "question1", value:5, explaination : "answer1", 
      answers: [ {content: "aaa", correct: true},{content: "bbb", correct: false},{content: "ccc", correct: false},{content: "ddd", correct: false}]
    } ,
      { id: 2, question : "question2", value:10, explaination : "answer1", 
      answers: [ {content: "eee", correct: true},{content: "fff", correct: false},{content: "ggg", correct: false},{content: "hhhh", correct: false} ]
      }
    ])

  const [submitQuiz, setSubmitQuiz] = useState(false);
  const [executedSet, setExecutedSet] = useState(false);

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [question, setQuestion]=useState('')
  const [answer, setAnswer]=useState('')
  const [dropdown, setDropdown]=useState("")


  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (props.location.state){
        console.log(props.location.state)

        setQuiz(props.location.state)
        setQuestionList(props.location.state.questions)
        setExecutedSet(true)    
      }
      console.log(quiz)
    },[]) 

  const addQuestionButton = () => {
    setQuestion({question: "", value:0, explaination: "", answers :  [ {content: "", correct: false},{content: "", correct: false},{content: "", correct: false},{content: "", correct: false} ] })
    setShow(true)
  };

  const editQuestionButton = (question) =>{
    console.log(question)
    setQuestion(question)
    setAnswerList(question.answers)
    setShow(true)
  }



    return (
    <div className='page'>

      <h2>Questions</h2>
      
      <button onClick={()=> addQuestionButton()}>Add Question</button>   

      {questionList.map((question, index)=>(
          <div key={index}>
            ID: {question.id} Question: {question.question}
            <br/>
            <button onClick={()=> editQuestionButton(question)}>Edit Question</button>  
            <button onClick={()=> removeQuestionButton(question)}>Remove Question</button>  
            <br/>
            <br/>
            
          </div>
      ))}

    <Modal show={show} backdrop="static" keyboard={false} state={question}>

      <Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Title>Adding Question Form</Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>

      <Modal.Body>
        <Form>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="question">Question</label>
            <input value={question.question} onChange={(e)=>setQuestion({...question, question: e.target.value})} type="text" 
            className="form-control stuff" id="question" placeholder="Enter question name" required/>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="value">Value</label>
            <input value={question.value} onChange={(e)=>setQuestion({...question, value: e.target.value})} type="number" className="form-control stuff" id="value" required/>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="explaination">Explaination</label>
            <input value={question.explaination} onChange={(e)=>setQuestion({...question, explaination: e.target.value})} type="text" 
            className="form-control stuff" id="explaination" placeholder="Enter Correct Explaination" required/>
          </div>
          <br/>

          { answerList.map((answer, index)=>(
          <div key={index}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="explaination">Answer {index + 1}</label>


              <input onChange={ (e) => {
                console.log(index)
                setAnswer({...answer, content: e.target.value})}

              } value={answer.content} type="text" 
              className="form-control stuff" id="explaination" placeholder="Enter answer display words" required/>

            </div>
          </div>
          ))}

        </Form>
      </Modal.Body>

      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-dark" onClick={()=> setShow(false)}> Close </Button>
        <Button onClick={handleSubmitQuestion} type="button" className="btn btn-primary submit" id="submit">Submit</Button>
      </Modal.Footer>

    </Modal>

    </div>);

}
```

Comment: @VitaliyRayets props.location works fine

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the value of the input is coming from the `answerList` state (`answerList.map(answer => ...)`) but the onChange is updating a separate state called `answer`. You are getting confused because the argument you are passing to your .map and the state you want to update both have the same name: `answer`. But these are not the same.

This can be demonstrated by changing the name of the argument of the .map. You would be left with something like this:

```
{answerList.map((differentName, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor="explaination">Answer {index + 1}</label>

      <input
        onChange={(e) => {
          console.log(index);
          setAnswer({ ...answer, content: e.target.value });
        }}
        value={differentName.content}
        type="text"
        className="form-control stuff"
        id="explaination"
        placeholder="Enter answer display words"
        required
      />
    </div>
  </div>
))};
}
```

In order to change the value of the input, you have to make the onChange target the correct value.

Comment: Hi yes thankyou for the clarification, this makes sense but I am unsure how to target a specific answer instance within a setState correctly given it is an array of elements. Do you have a suggestion for this?

Comment: Yes, I suggest you break off this answer input into its own component with its own component state. That way you can manipulate that state easily and use it for rendering the value of the input.

Comment: So instead of having it in the same component, do something like answerList.map(element => (<AnswerInput/>)). Then you can have answer state in the AnswerInput component.

Comment: What data do you need to pass to the parent? Maybe you could share a link to your repo and I could take a look. It's hard to get into these kinds of specifics on Stack Overflow because I only have a very general idea of your project and its purposes. Feel free to add me on Discord and I can help you more @jevoncochran